How to estimate a date given data on past dates?
I am working on a free visa timeline tracker to let people estimate how long the UK Home Office will take to respond to their applications. I don't know much about statistics, only basic school statistics like standard deviation. Sorry if this is off topic, I didn't know a better place to ask. My background is in software development.
The data I have is a list of entries: [Submission Date, Response Date]. I have 0-5 entries for any particular Submission Date.
The data will always be several weeks out of date.
One approach could be to collect up to n (maybe 30) entries by going to the given Submission Date, then the day before, then day after, then 2 days before etc - and then calculate the mean time taken.
Another approach could be to collect all entries from the last 30 days and and calculate the mean time taken.
I could use one of these basic algorithms but I'm not sure what would be the best one.
Given a new Submission Date, how can I estimate the Response Date?

Please excuse me if the question doesn't have the right tags, this is my first post here.

One thing I would do is determine if there is any trend in the data. If there is no trend, then I would plot all the data as a histogram to see how it is distributed. Waiting times, are frequently exponentially distributed, but obviously not always, and probably not so here as there is likely a minimum possible wait time.

How one should characterize how long it takes depends on the probability distribution. To fully characterize such times, one should extract the distribution's parameters, and it is not always the mean waiting time that is the most important one.
